# Conditional redirection with logout

Tags: redirect, logout

I've been asked to implement a custom redirection in WordPress. It seemed quite simple at first but I have no idea how to get it right. So much that I can't even get started with it.
This is how it should go:

- The user logs in, and the database gets queried using the `wp_login` hook
- If a certain condition is met, the user gets logged out using `wp_logout()` from the wp_login hook
- This is where the problem comes in, the user should get redirected to a page dedicated to them, without breaking the normal logout function

So if the user logs out normally, they get redirected to the default page, however if the condition is met they get redirected to another page and still get logged out.

I've tried the `wp_logout` and `wp_clear_auth_cookie` hooks, but to no avail.
I can't really show you any code, as I did not manage to come up with anything concrete.

edit:

```
 ....
 //in the login hook
 if($condition)
    wp_logout();
 ...
 add_action("wp_login","login_hook",10,2);

 //below the login hook
 function logout(){
    if($condition){
      wp_redirect(home_url("/redirectTo"));
      exit; 
     }
  }
 add_action("wp_logout","logout");
```

Comment: Maybe add some kind of `if($condition) { header("Location: /page"); }` to the `wp_logout` hook. 

The action to hook off is on line 603 of `pluggable.php` according to the codex link.

add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );

`$function_to_add` will be the one working out the condition to generate the `header` parameter? 

Thinking out loud!

Comment: That problem is that I should be somehow passing the condition to the logout hook, and I have no idea how. I'll edit my post to show you what I've got.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass anything back just add an extra action to perform as part of it. It's not my expertise but I've put my suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wp_logout()` function is [pluggable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions). You should be able to write your own version and "overload" the Core function:

```
function wp_logout() {

  $lid = get_current_user_id(); 

  wp_destroy_current_session();
  wp_clear_auth_cookie();

  do_action( 'wp_logout' );
  /**
    * Fires after a user is logged-out.
    *
    * @since 1.5.0
    */
  if (2 == $lid) {
    wp_redirect(home_url("/redirectTo"));
    exit; 
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but I don't really know WordPress, would this go into my theme's function.php or the pluggable.php file?

Comment: Theme! ALWAYS theme to prevent overwriting during updates. Put it in your `functions.php` in your theme directory

Comment: Thank you, and if I'm correct I don't need the add_action() call, right?

Comment: Also if the condition is false, will this work as usual?

Comment: If the condition doesn't match, it should work as normal.

Comment: I just had the time to test the code, but it seems that when I call wp_logout, the default wp_logout function gets called, not the one you wrote.

Comment: Where is your code? I tested mine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The action to hook off is on line 603 of `pluggable.php` according to the codex link.

`add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );` is the format you should use so it would probably look something like:

```
 add_action( 'wp_logout' , 'logout_page' );

 function logout_page() {
   // Work out your conditions 

     if($condition1) {
       $page = *page*; // whatever page
     } else if ($condition2) {
       $page = *page*; // whatever page
     }

   header("Location: /$page");
  }
```

I haven't done much with the logout hook but unless the function has already output something (which it would seem unlikely at that stage) the header should take you to the right page.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that to work out my conditions I need the users ID as it's all coming from the database and if I use get_current_user() all I'll get will be null.

Comment: If you set a high `$priority` your action should be performed before the user is logged out and you should be able to use `get_current_user_id()` ??

Comment: The function `wp_destroy_current_session()` uses `get_current_user_id()` so you should still be able to use it